# Grouping by and filtering for an agg function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science

I am trying to calculate avg weight under two columns , sex and type as the df is below:

```
sex |  type     | weight
 M     Obese      305
 F     Normal     100
 M     Underweight 105
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `filter` wrong here. Pass in the thing you want to retain to the `like` argument:

```
df.groupby(['sex','type'])['weight'].mean().filter(like='Obese')
```

Output:

```
sex  type 
M    Obese    305
Name: weight, dtype: int64
```

Comment: If it's just two you could just filter twice, i.e. `filter(like='Obese').filter(like='M')`.

Comment: Otherwise it's probably better to do it in two steps. First get the mean and then use boolean indexing with multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'sex': ['M', 'F', 'M'], 'type':['obese', 'Normal' ,'Underweight'],
    'weight': [305, 100, 105]})
print(df[df['type'] == 'obese']['weight'].mean())
```

First, I don't think you need the filter() function, it's doing something different from you thought. Secondly, you always want to select or 'filter' first, then do the calculation.

Hope this helps.